# Unable to set width/height to an img when DOCTYPE is set (Firefox)

Tags: html, css, firefox, doctype

Imagine three images with fixed size:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
        div.photos img {
            width: 320px;
            height: 240px;
            background-color: black;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="photos">
        <img src="abc" />
        <img src="def" />
        <img src="ghi" />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

When you [look at such page](http://jsfiddle.net/wDQw6/) in IE or Chrome, you'll see what I expected - threee images with fixed sizes.
In Firefox however, it doesn't work.

But if I set the images to `display: block;` or remove the `DOCTYPE` (doesn't show on jsfiddle) it works.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Testing your code on Firefox 14, using references to real images in place of abc, def, ghi, does not exhibit such a problem. Please specify what “doesn’t work” means, which version of Firefox you used in testing, and which exact code you used (including references to available images). Your jsfiddle differs from the included code and does not refer to actual images, so it demonstrates what happens in absence of images at the specified addresses (something that browsers are known to handle differently).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela, Well that's exactly the problem - that's why I set the size to the images so that the design doesn't break when they fail to load. "something that browsers are known to handle differently" - well, it's not well known to me, so I was searching for the reason why and which behaviour should be considered correct.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, I though it was about images proper, but it’s about the rendering when an image is not available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be an old feature in Firefox: I found a [discussion](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t548942-firefox-ignores-img-height-width.html) about it from year 2007:

So I suppose it’s intentional and won’t go away. I guess they might be thinking this way: Everything is fine if you set dimensions on an image, we’ll scale it. But if the image is missing, we will render the alternative text instead, and this changes the `img` element from a replaced inline element to a *text*, a non-replaced inline element, and for it we won’t support `height` and `width`, by the spec. Instead, the text determines the dimensions. And presumably the authors of Firefox think this is the right thing to do, and only in Quirks Mdoe do they do as other browsers do.

If you add `alt` attributes (as you should, every `img` should have one), you’ll see how the box size varies by text length. Apparently Firefox treats a missing `alt` here as equivalent to `alt=""`, implying zero width.

This would explain why setting `display` to `inline-block` (or `block`) changes the behavior: then `width` and `height` are applied.

Comment: @Mr.Alien, me neither and I am webcoding for a very long time already. Depends on just how you use your images. In my case right now, in a mini gallery that is part of the page design, an empty image of correct size is preferable to a shrunk border.

Answer (score 1):

I think firefox wont be applying height and width to `<img>` element which are empty and hence it must be rendering like that, so use CSS `display: block;`

Here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wDQw6/1/)

Or use an image and see...

Updated : **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wDQw6/2/)**

Comment: Thanks but I already ''understood'' that but why and why does removing doctype change the behaviour? And why only firefox? Is that the correct behaviour or the wrong one? (mind you, the fix here is obvious, I'm trying to learn why is ff behaving like this)

Comment: @Czechnology doctype sets rules to your html elements, so when using a doctype firefox says oo its doctype html so it would render the markup accordingly..

Comment: The fix isn’t that obvious, and it should be `display: inline-block` to make the boxes appear side by side, not vertically.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela No one specified side-by-side

Comment: Side-by-side is implicit in the markup I think: if the images were available, they would appear that way.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Actually we don't know how he want's the image to be displayed

Comment: The main issue are the empty pictures collapsing, not whether they're `block` or `inline-block`.