# positioning image nearest to absolute positioned div

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I have the following html

```
<div id="someid">
    <img src="" />
    <div class="someclass"></div>
</div>
<div id="other">
</div>
```

And the following css

```
#someid{position: relative;}
.someclass{position: absolute; left: 100px; width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red;}
img{floa/t: left; background-color: blue; width: 100px; height: 100px;}
#other{width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: green; position: relative;}
```

I don't need image to be floated left.
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XPUVC/3/)

The green-background div should go below. This demo is working in chrome exactly what I want but not in Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: Demo is updated with .someclass{top: 0;}

Comment: you want to be this http://jsfiddle.net/rohit_azad/XPUVC/5/

Comment: @RohitAzad I din't see any change in your fiddle but I need exactly like that but is it possible with out using float: left to img.

Comment: Do you really need to omit `float:left;`?

Comment: @code-jaff Yes, I don't need to use float left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually possible without `float:left;`, but i'm not sure whether you actually need an absolutely positioned `div`.

**Note: Without absolute `div`**

```
#someid {
    position: relative;
}
.someclass {
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
img {
    /*float: left;*/
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
#other {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    position: relative;
}
```

***for firefox***

They just ignore the `width` and `height`, therefore however you need to change the display as a block level element, then they will be applied.

[Unable to set width/height to an img when DOCTYPE is set (Firefox)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11637886/1592398)

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7ekpZ/2/)

**EDIT: with absolute positioned div**

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7ekpZ/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Add `clear:both`

```
#other{width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: green; position: relative; clear:both}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XPUVC/4/)**

Comment: Note to img{float: left;} is disabled. I don't need to use float: left; then your demo would not work. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your styling for the 'img' element seems to contain some typo (floa/t: left; )

Comment: That means I have disabled to float: left;

Comment: Ideally, this should have been a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

**[WORKING SOLUTION](http://jsfiddle.net/kYzAb/)**

**The HTML:**

```
<div id="someid">
    <img src="" />
    <div class="someclass"></div>
</div>
<div id="other">
</div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
#someid{position: relative;height:100px;}
.someclass{position: absolute;top:100px; left: 100px; width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red;}
img{/*float: left;*/display:inline-block; background-color: blue; width: 100px; height: 100px;}
#other{width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: green; position: relative;}
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `display:inline-block` to `img`.

http://jsfiddle.net/XPUVC/8/

Answer (score 0):

[Demo link](http://jsfiddle.net/XPUVC/12/).

```
img{float: left; background-color: #0D2DB4; width: 100px; height: 100px;}
#someid{position: relative;overflow: hidden;}
```